# ITMS-90096: Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to submit my iOS app on app store, But I get the following error :

[image]

I googled it and found a few solutions BUT I don't want to use `launch screen`, All solutions say that I should add launch image, But my app have a `splash view controller`, So I don't want to use `launch screen`.

How I should fix this issue ?

Comment: You can't use a view controller for the launch image. You must either use a static image or a launch storyboard.

Comment: I am using the LaunchScreen.storyboard but still getting the same error. Please help me if you have any trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple clearly states in [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) that

> the launch image isn’t an opportunity to provide:
>
> - An “app entry experience,” such as a splash screen
> - An About window
> - Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your app’s first
>   screen
>
> A launch file or image provides
>
> - simple placeholder that iOS displays when your app starts up
> - is quickly replaced by the first screen of your app

Launch screen is supposed to be visible while your app loads. If your app loads fast enough, the launch screen might not be visible long enough for you to notice.

Also,

> Every app must supply a launch file or at least one static image.

So, your splash view controller can be the first screen of your app but launch screen OR image is mandatory.